# Required field error, while i am sending the data via python request or Ajax request

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, api, python-requests

[I am sending the data in the same format as API documentation says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqrLY.png)

```
https://dev.switchere.com/#tag/Partner-API/paths/~1partner~1order~1fee/post
```

**API documentation is here.**

Python requests,

```js
import requests


postData = {
    "payin_currency": "USD",
    "payout_currency": "BTC",
    "payin_amount": 10.01,
    "payout_amount": 10.02,
    "free_first": 1
}
url = "https://switchere.com/api/v1/public/order/fee/"

response = requests.post(url=url, data=postData)

response.text


Response: 
'{"error":{"payin_currency":"REQUIRED","payin_or_payout_amount":"REQUIRED","payout_currency":"REQUIRED"}}'
```

> AJAX request example

I tried this using ajax request also. here's my code. It also gave me an error.

```js
let postData = {
                        "payin_currency": "XRP",
                        "payout_currency": "USD",
                        "payin_amount": 10.01,
                        "free_first": 0
                        }

                {#axios here#}
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    url: "https://switchere.com/api/v1/public/order/fee",
                    data: postData,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data)
                        debugger;
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
                      {#console.log(xhr.statusText);#}
                      {#console.log(textStatus);#}
                      console.log(error);
                  }

                })
```

GET https://switchere.com/api/v1/public/order/fee?callback=jQuery34007279579386571398_1603938433094&payin_currency=XRP&payout_currency=USD&payin_amount=10.01&free_first=0&_=1603938433095 net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Comment: This seems like a server issue. I think you should also contact the owner of the API, because your code, from my side, looks okay.